# Selectively output columns from a text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to parse a log file, where I would like to get the first column and the text which follows a pattern.

The log file would look like this,

```
2018-04-25 00:00:10,139 INFO  [HiveServer2-HttpHandler-Pool: Thread-2678420]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(185)) - Parsing command: show databases
```

I would like the final output which contains timestamp ( first and second column ) and all commands which is followed by keyword `command:`.

Is there a clean way of getting this? Currently, my plan is to use `awk` to fetch columns 1 and 2. Use `sed` to get the commands and then to merge the two outputs to a new file.

Comment: This seems a log from tomcat/wildfly you can alternativelly export it with with open office calc and the colums will be sorted for you. Else show me some code so I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it with `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' -f1,2,12- ${YOUR_LOG_FILE}
```

Or (safer):

```
cat ${YOUR_LOG_FILE} | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f1,2,11-
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
awk -F'(,|command:)' '{print $1, $NF}' infile
2018-04-25 00:00:10  show databases
```

Here we defined field separators either a comma `,` or string `command:`, then print the first and last fields.